# Highlighter for a broswer

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, internet-explorer, portable

Just something that can used to highlight text on a page in a way that can be viewed later (after refresh, etc).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be very similar to what you are looking for:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6219 (Firefox)
- http://www.microsoft.com/windows/ie/ie6/previous/webaccess/ie5wa.mspx (Internet Explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [Diigo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oojbgadfejifecebmdnhhkbhdjaphole) extension (for Google Chrome) will do the job.